# Can adding FK or PK constraints invalidate something?

Tags: oracle, constraints, alter-table

I  have a couple of tables with primary-foreign key relations but those constraints do not actually exist. Now I want to add them with an `alter table` statement.

Will those commands cause any object that depends on the tables to become invalid?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good question. Let's poke the database and see. Here's the set up:

```
SQL> create table p23 (id number not null, col1 varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> create table c23 (id number not null, p_id number not null, col1 varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> create or replace procedure tst23
  2  is
  3  begin
  4    insert into p23 values (1, 'ABC');
  5    insert into c23 values (11, 1, 'DEF');
  6  end;
  7  /

Procedure created.

SQL> select status from user_objects where object_name = 'TST23';

STATUS
-------
VALID

SQL>
```

Everything is copacetic. Now we'll add some constraints.

```
SQL> alter table p23 add constraint p23_pk primary key (id);

Table altered.

SQL> select status from user_objects where object_name = 'TST23';

STATUS
-------
VALID

SQL> alter table c23 add constraint c23_p23_fk 
  2      foreign key (p_id) references p23;

Table altered.

SQL> select status from user_objects where object_name = 'TST23';

STATUS
-------
VALID

SQL>
```

All is still cool. But when we change a table's structure this happens...

```
SQL> alter table p23 add col2 date;

Table altered.

SQL> select status from user_objects where object_name = 'TST23';

STATUS
-------
INVALID

SQL>
```

... which is exactly what we would want.

Note that I ran these tests on 11gR2. Oracle introduced fine-grained dependency tracking in 11g, which made programmatic objects more robust when we run DDL on their dependencies. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_dependencies.htm). So the outcome might be different in earlier versions. It pays to test.

---

> " what is the reason for the procedure to become invalid?"

Structural changes such as adding, modifying or dropping a column potentially have an impact on referencing objects. The procedure had insert statements which didn't specify target columns. So adding a column introduced an `ORA-00947: not enough values` bug.

But suppose we employed good practice and specified columns?

```
SQL> create or replace procedure tst23
  2  is
  3  begin
  4      insert into p23 (id, col1) values (1, 'ABC');
  5  end;
  6  /

Procedure created.

SQL> select status from user_objects where object_name = 'TST23';

STATUS
-------
VALID

SQL> alter table p23 add col4 number;

Table altered.

SQL> select status from user_objects where object_name = 'TST23';

STATUS
-------
VALID

SQL>
```

Now we're protected by fine-grained dependency tracking. Well, sort of. We shouldn't substitute dependency tracking for impact analysis:

```
SQL> alter table p23 add col5 date not null;

Table altered.

SQL> select status from user_objects where object_name = 'TST23';

STATUS
-------
VALID

SQL>
```

The procedure has a VALID state but it will still fail when we run it, because it doesn't populate the new mandatory column.

Comment: A well-drafted answer, I would like to know what is the reason for the procedure to become invalid?

Comment: APC, thanks for your very-detailed answer and explanation. Do you think that it's cover all the cases? (I mean - adding pk+fk will never make an invalid?)

Comment: I think so but my advice is to check the specific circumstance you're interested in.